# Work log that can't be edited but can be added to

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, write-protect

I want to find a way of creating a document such that once an entry is finished the existing entries are locked for editing however further entries can be added. This is to serve as a record of work completed. I particularly want it in this format so that it is possible to quickly look back over a number of entries without having to open separate documents.

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this within word? Or in any other program come to that.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is just a work log, I'm assuming that text will do.  In that case, just combine the newest entries with the existing file and create a new file with today's date.  i.e. start with 101213.log for today, and when finished entering the info & saving, mark the file readonly.  Then use whatever method (i.e. cmd file input) to get a new entry, and add that entry to the existing file with a command like

```
COPY <multiple_file_list> <single_file>
```

i.e. COPY 101213.log+101313.log 101313.log

Alternatively you can keep separate files for each day and then use a command like

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt
```

or use any of the various merge methods explained at http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001376.htm  if you don't want to use text files.

The following short cmd script will also do this;  I use it in a way that is similar to what you mention, where I can create an entry each day & combine them.  Note this is not elegant but very easy to understand (I hope) in that the "Write It!" is the prompt to the user;  this is for running from a shortcut in Windows, and I don't bother to set read-only on the file, but you could easily do so.

```
@echo off
copy loggit.txt loggit.tmp > nothing.txt
set /p tmpvar="Write it! "
echo %tmpvar% > tempfil.txt
@echo off
copy loggit.tmp+ tempfil.txt loggit.txt > nothing.txt
del tempfil.txt
del loggit.tmp
del nothing.txt
exit
```

This will open a cmd window with the prompt "Write It! " and then when you type in a line & hit enter, the window closes & the input is taken for the next entry in the file.  For your use, I'd suggest adding the date stamp to the file contents.